# Como gerar 200.000 primos o mais rápido possível em Python?

Tags: python, matemática

> **Atenção:** Não estou procurando por pedaços de código prontos. Quero apenas que alguém me ajude a *pensar* em alguma forma de gerar esses 200.000 primos da forma mais eficiente possível, em Python.

Estou resolvendo a questão [#61 do CodeAbbey](http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/prime-numbers-generation), mas não estou conseguindo pensar em como gerar os primos que o exercício pede.

O enunciado, basicamente, considera que existe uma lista que contém todos os números primos do mundo, a começar pelo 2. Com base nessa lista, o enunciado dá uma série de índices (índices dessa lista), e o programa tem que retornar o primo que ocupa esse índice nessa lista imaginária.

Ex.:

> Na lista [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, ...], o índice 1 é 3; o
> 2 é 5, ...

O enunciado garante que a série de índices que ele vai fornecer aleatoriamente não possui nenhum índice superior a 200.000 (por isso 200.000 primos, no máximo)

Exemplo de input e output:

```
input data:
7 1 199999 4    # são os índices da lista imaginária

answer:
19 3 2750131 11    # são os primos dessa lista, correspondentes aos índices acima
```

No final do enunciado, o CodeAbbey avisa que existe uma forma de gerar o resultado em +/- 1 segundo.

Deixei o meu programa rodando por 10 minutos e não gerou resultado. Talvez um segundo seja muito pouco tempo, mas com certeza tem como resolver em... menos de 20 segundos?

Para tentar resolver, estou implantando o Sieve of Eratosthene (ou [Crivo de Eratóstenes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crivo_de_Erat%C3%B3stenes))

Segue meu código atual:

```
from math import sqrt

def primos(n, maxIndex):
    maiorCheck = int(sqrt(n))
    lista = []
    i, x, qtdPrimos = 0, 0, 0
    for m in range(2, n+1):
        lista.append(m)
    while x <= maiorCheck:
        x = lista[i]
        i += 1
        for numero in lista:
            if numero != x:
                if numero % x == 0:
                    lista[lista.index(numero)] = 0
        while 0 in lista:
            del lista[lista.index(0)]
        if len(lista) == maxIndex:
            x = maiorCheck + 1
    return lista

qtdPrimos = int(input('Entre com a quantidade de primos a serem impressos: ').strip())

indexes = input('Entre com os índices para os quais serão retornados primos: ').strip().split()
result = []

for n in range(len(indexes)):
    indexes[n] = int(indexes[n])

arrayPrimos = primos(2750131, max(indexes))

for m in range(len(indexes)):
    result.append(str(arrayPrimos[indexes[m]-1]))

print('\n--- R E S U L T A D O ---\n'+' '.join(result))
```

Comment: Boa pergunta. Eu mesmo consegui fazer em 12 segundos no console do Chrome, gostaria de saber como fazer mais rápido.

Comment: A pergunta é uma das mais bem feitas do site, o título nem tanto. Esse requisito de tempo é complicado.

Comment: @bigown Melhorei o título, deixando o requisito de tempo menos rigoroso.

Comment: Maninho tenho um exemplo em Java que produz primos de forma bastante rápida talvez possa te ajudar link: https://github.com/HallefBruno/Estrutura-de-dados/blob/master/primo.java

Comment: Então, lá não diz que consegue em 1 segundo em Python. Pode ser que demore 3 vezes, ou 10 vezes só porque é Python. Não estou dizendo que faz, mas pode ser. Ali faz uma afirmação ingênua. Tem um jeito de fazer ficar mais rápido ainda. Faz algo que distribui o cálculo em 1000 máquinas ou pelo menos *cores*. Quando eles escreveram isso era um tempo, as máquinas evoluíram. Imagine que isso escrito na década de 90 hoje daria com um algoritmo horrível.

Comment: Um dos problemas mais complexos que existe é gerar primos, o problema vai se agravando quanto mais números deseja. Tem algoritmos complexos que podem ir melhorando, eu nem vi seu código, mas não precisa verificar tudo. Eu nem optei pelas sacanagens que é não gerar os primos e sim fornecê-los :) Veja https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin

Answer (score 50):

Com o próprio Crivo de Eratóstenes eu consegui resultados bem satisfatórios. Vale lembrar que, como o crivo retorna a lista de todos os números primos menores que o valor de entrada, teremos que informar o maior valor primo que o programa aceitará. O enunciado fala que é garantido que não será solicitado um número após o 200.000°, então inicialmente devemos conhecer qual é este valor: [2.750.159](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=200000th%20prime%20number).

Uma implementação bastante simples do crivo é:

```
def sieve_of_eratosthene(N):

    # Cria-se uma lista referente a todos os inteiros entre 0 e N:
    A = [True] * (N+1)

    # Define os números 0 e 1 como não primos:
    A[0] = A[1] = False

    # Percorra a lista até encontrar o primeiro número primo:
    for value, prime in enumerate(A):

        # O número é primo?
        if prime:

            # Retorna o número primo:
            yield value

            # Remova da lista todos os múltiplos do número encontrado:
            for i in range(value**2, N+1, value):
                A[i] = False
```

Assim, podemos obter todos os 200.000 primeiros números primos fazendo:

```
primes = list(sieve_of_eratosthene(2750159))
```

E gerar a saída da seguinte forma:

```
print("Saída:", [primes[i] for i in [7, 1, 199999, 4]]) # Saída: [19, 3, 2750159, 11]
```

Sendo `[7, 1, 199999, 4]` a entrada do programa.

> **Nota:** o 199.999° número primo será 2.750.131, como esperado, apenas se o número 2 ocupar o índice 1. Considerando que a implementação define o índice 0 para o valor 2, o valor esperado na saída seria referente ao índice 199.998°.

Utilizando o módulo [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/timeit.html) para a medição do tempo, obtive um tempo médio, em 100 execuções, de `0.69539769177063s`.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/EXzV83).

**Uma breve explicação do código**

A primeira linha da função, `A = [True] * (N+1)` cria uma lista de `N+1` elementos, todos definidos como `True`, indicando inicialmente que todos os valores entre 0 e N são números primos. Logo após, é definido os valores 0 e 1 como `False`, indicando que estes não são números primos. E com um laço de repetição, é percorrido todos os outros valores e sempre que achar um valor primo, retorne-o e elimina da lista, definindo como `False`, todos os números que são múltiplos desse primo encontrado. Para uma melhor visualização, a lista `A` seria algo como:

```
A = [False, False, True, True, False, True, False, ...]
```

Indicando que 0 não é primo, 1 não é primo, 2 é primo, 3 é primo, 4 não é primo, 5 é primo, 6 não é primo, assim sucessivamente. O que a função `enumerate` faz é retornar um par de valores onde o primeiro representa o índice na lista e o segundo o valor propriamente dito. Assim, fazendo `enumerate(A)`, seria retornado algo semelhante à:

```
[(0, False), (1, False), (2, True), (3, True), (4, False), (5, True), (6, False), ...]
```

E é por isso que no `for` existem dois valores. O primeiro valor retornado de `enumerate` é atribuído à `value` e o segundo à `prime`, assim, quando `prime` for verdadeiro, sabemos que `value` será um número primo.

```
for value, prime in enumerate(A):
    ...
```

Já o `yield` faz o papel do `return`, porém, para um [gerador](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). Confesso que eu acabei complicando mais que o necessário neste código utilizando um gerador, pois visto que o gerador deverá ser convertido para uma lista, eu poderia gerá-la diretamente. O código ficaria assim:

```
def sieve_of_eratosthene(N):
    
    # Lista de números primos:
    numbers = []
 
    # Cria-se uma lista referente a todos os inteiros entre 0 e N:
    A = [True] * (N+1)
 
    # Define os números 0 e 1 como não primos:
    A[0] = A[1] = False
 
    # Percorra a lista até encontrar o primeiro número primo:
    for value, prime in enumerate(A):
 
        # O número é primo?
        if prime:
 
            # Retorna o número primo:
            numbers.append(value)
 
            # Remova da lista todos os múltiplos do número enontrado:
            for i in range(value**2, N+1, value):
                A[i] = False
                
    return numbers
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/XIxgue).

Perceba que a principal diferença é que onde antes eu utilizada o `yield`, agora utilizei o `append` de uma lista.

**Uma implementação extra**

Assim como comentado pelo LINQ em sua resposta, o fato de ter que conhecer de antemão o *n*-ésimo valor primo pode ser considerado um limitante da solução. Uma alternativa prática é aplicar o conceito matemático apresentado no final desta resposta para calcular um valor primo próximo ao desejado. Sabendo que o *n*-ésimo número primo, Pn, é menor que `n ln(n) + n ln(ln(n))`, se calcularmos todos os valores primos até este valor temos certeza que teremos calculado o valor de Pn. Algo como:

```
def sieve_of_eratosthene(N):
    
    N = floor(N*log(N) + N*(log(log(N))))
    
    # Lista de números primos:
    numbers = []
 
    # Cria-se uma lista referente a todos os inteiros entre 0 e N:
    A = [True] * (N+1)
 
    # Define os números 0 e 1 como não primos:
    A[0] = A[1] = False
 
    # Percorra a lista até encontrar o primeiro número primo:
    for value, prime in enumerate(A):
 
        # O número é primo?
        if prime:
 
            # Retorna o número primo:
            numbers.append(value)
 
            # Remova da lista todos os múltiplos do número encontrado:
            for i in range(value**2, N+1, value):
                A[i] = False
                
    return numbers
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/a8DlLE).

Apenas com a adição da primeira linha, agora podemos chamar a função `sieve_of_eratosthene(2e5)` para obter os 200.000 primeiros números primos. Na verdade, obtém-se até mais, por isso o tempo de execução pode aumentar.

---

**Possível alternativa**

É provado matematicamente, se entendi bem, que o *n*-ésimo número primo, sendo *n* maior ou igual a 6, pertencerá ao conjunto de números definido por:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo, para `n = 199999`, é obtido o seguinte conjunto:

```
2741586 < P_n < 2941585
```

Que contém o valor esperado 2750159; porém, este não será o único número primo neste intervalo, então o desafio seguindo esta lógica seria identificar corretamente o valor dentro do intervalo.

Comment: Excelente! Muito bom! Agora foi muito rápido.

Comment: Mas eu não entendi um monte de coisas que você fez na função _sieve_of_eratosthene_...

Pode me apontar os conceitos que você usou pra eu pesquisar? Sou novato ainda...

Comment: @santosmarco_ que conceitos seriam esses que não entendeu?

Comment: Então... Tem algumas coisas que ainda não aprendi, mas que adoraria pesquisar sobre. Na função que você criou, a partir da linha do for (inclusive) até a última.

Comment: Por exemplo: 1) Porque dois valores, separados por vírgula no primeiro for; 2) O que é o enumerate(A); 3) Como ele identifica que é prime apenas com “if prime”?; 4) O que é o yield; 5) e o último for eu não entendi... Porque começa com value ** 2, o que é essa variável value, e porque transformar o item da lista em False o elimina?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Se você juntar este algoritmo pra descobrir um conjunto em que o n-ésimo primo se encontra junto com o algoritmo do crivo, consegue deixar a solução mais genérica. Funcionando para "qualquer" número primo.

Comment: @santosmarco_ assim que possível adiciono à resposta as explicações

Comment: Segundo o enunciado do link o índice 7 não deveria retornar 17 ?

Comment: @MagicHat não, 19 mesmo. O índice começa em 0, então é o oitavo valor da lista.

Comment: Ah,sim saquei, sua lista tem alcance de 0 a 199999...

Comment: @santosmarco_ Perdoe-me, acabei me perdendo nos meus horários e esqueci de editar a resposta aquele dia. Já adicionei uma breve explicação e uma solução alternativa ao `yield`. Veja se esclarece melhor suas dúvidas, se é que ainda as tem.

Comment: Estava pensando nessa pergunta ontem :), depois vou testar as propostas

Comment: Esta resposta é fantástica. Coloquei uma recompensa na pergunta para chamar a atenção e no final do prazo, darei os +100 para você.

Answer (score 18):

Minha contribuição é uma implementação um tanto **ingênua**. Leva (na minha máquina) aproximadamente 71 segundos para gerar 200.000 primos. Apesar disso, é uma implementação básica, não usa nada de terceiros e é bem fácil de entender.

Nesta implementação, **não é necessário saber de antemão** qual é o n-ésimo número primo, ou seja, é possível criar uma lista com **qualquer quantidade** de números primos.

Note que não é uma adaptação do seu código, foi criado do zero. O algoritmo consiste em ir procurando de "forma bruta", checando todos os números ímpares.

O algoritmo se baseia na afirmação de que um número é composto (não-primo) se, se somente se, houver algum divisor **primo** menor ou igual a sua raiz quadrada.

```
from math import sqrt, ceil
import time

def checkPrime(num):
    if num % 2 == 0: return False
    i = 3
    while i <= ceil(sqrt(num)):
        if num % i == 0: 
            return False
        i += 2
    return True

def primes(q):
    primelist = [2]
    number = 3
    while len(primelist) < q:
        if(checkPrime(number)):
            primelist.append(number)        
        number += 2    
    return primelist
```

#### Versão 2

Este leva 24 segundos (na mesma máquina) pra gerar os 200.000 primos. A diferença deste pro outro é que, na checagem pra saber se um número é primo ou não, são usados apenas os números primos já conhecidos.

Isso porque, como eu disse acima, um número é composto (não-primo) quando tem algum divisor **primo** menor ou igual a sua raiz quadrada.

```
def checkPrime(num, baseList):    
    for p in baseList:
        if(p > ceil(sqrt(num))): break

        if num % p == 0:
            return False
    return True

def primes(q):
    primelist, number = [2], 3

    while len(primelist) < q:
        if checkPrime(number, primelist):
            primelist.append(number)
        number += 2
    return primelist
```

O uso seria assim:

```
def main():
    lista = primes(200000)
    print("Saída: ", [lista[i] for i in [199999, 1, 7]])
```

> **Saída**: [2750159, 3, 19]

Comment: Este último a saída não está errada ? Para os índices  199999 e 7, segundo o link do enunciado...]

Comment: @MagicHat Só vai ser daquele jeito se começar a contar do 1

Comment: "Eles estarão no alcance de 1 para 200000. ";)

Comment: @MagicHat É só diminuir 1 da entrada do usuário e ser feliz, não vejo o porquê disso invalidar a resposta. O principal ponto é como gerar os números em um tempo aceitável e não fazer todo o exercício para o AP

Comment: Saquei, no caso sua resposta é legal tmb, por que como a do lacobus não é necessário saber o valor do último primo...

Comment: @MagicHat Na verdade tanto a resposta do Anderson quanto a Lacobus precisam saber de antemão qual é o último primo. A minha é mais genérica, mas, obviamente, tem um custo bem maior

Comment: Hum verdade num tinha reparado a do lacobus... Para mim a sua tá na frente, ficaria perfeita(pra mim) se a entrada e saída fossem idênticas a do enunciado, mas já entendi o motivo..;)

Comment: @MagicHat Na verdade, se você notar o meu método principal `main` é separado do resto do código justamente pra possibilitar isso, eu não postei o código que faz este _parsing_ porque acho que é uma questão secundária.

Comment: @LINQ Acabei adicionando uma linha de código na minha solução que permite não conhecer o n-ésimo número primo de antemão, sem afetar muito o desempenho. Talvez seja de seu interesse.

Comment: Talvez seja mais eficiente evitar a raiz quadrada e comparar `i**2 <= num` (primeira versão) ou `p**2 > num` (segunda versão)

Answer (score 10):

Cheguei atrasado na resposta. Porém, vou contribuir com uma implementação que é muito interessante e útil, porque ela **NÃO PRECISA DE LIMITE**.

Ela usa o algoritmo do 'crivo de Erastóthenes', porém de forma invertida, móvel, armazenando somente 1 múltiplo futuro de cada combinação de primos e liberando memória à medida que vai avançando, de forma que não é preciso definir de antemão qual o final do cálculo! E assim também não é preciso definir uma enorme lista na memória para ser marcada.

```
def eratosthenes():
    D = {}  # dicionario para armazenar os futuros primos
    q = 2   # primeiro inteiro a testar
    while True:
        if q not in D:
            yield q       # nao esta marcado entao eh primo
            D[q*q] = [q]  # armazena somente o primeiro multiplo 
                          # que ainda nao esta armazenado
        else:
            for p in D[q]:  # todos os nao-primos armazenados aqui precisam andar
                D.setdefault(p+q,[]).append(p)
            del D[q]        # libera memoria do que ja passou
        q += 1
```

Sendo assim, você pode chamar essa função e parar quando quiser, por exemplo

```
for p in eratosthenes():
    if p > 200000:
        break
    print(p)
```

Comment: Escrevendo na saída padrão demorou 1min22 segundos no meu WSL, jogando no `/dev/null` demorou 5.2s. A solução do Woss (imprimindo todos os números também) demorou 43s escrevendo na saída padrão, e 1.7s jogando no `/dev/null`. Fiz uma alteração para buscar apenas metade dos números na sua resposta (precisa passar por todos para fazer "andar" o crivo, mas não testo os pares, só os ímpares), os tempos foram 53s e 5.1s

Comment: Porém essa solução é infinita e a do Woss não é @JeffersonQuesado

Answer (score 7):

Código:

```
p = []

def gerar_primos():

    limite = 2750159 + 1

    primos = []
    nao_primo = set()

    for n in range( 2, limite ):

        if n in nao_primo:
            continue

        for f in range( n * 2, limite, n ):
            nao_primo.add( f )

        primos.append( n )

    return primos;


def primo(idx):

    global p

    if not p:
        p = gerar_primos();

    return p[ idx - 1 ]


print primo(7)
print primo(1)
print primo(199999)
print primo(4)
```

Saída:

```
$ time python primos.py 
17
2
2750131
7

real    0m1.963s
user    0m1.891s
sys 0m0.072s
```

Answer (score 2):

Sei um pouco de Java e estou aprendendo Python. Fiz esse algoritmo e ele calcula todos os números ímpares de forma extremamente rápida. No meu notebook ele calcula e imprime todos os números primos de 0 a 1.000.000 em menos de 3 segundos. E de 0 a 4.000.000 faz em cerca de 17 segundos.

```
import time

num2 = int(input("Informe até qual número procurar: "))
inicio = time.time()
print("Esses são os número primos entre 0 e %i"%num2)
# lista com o primeiro número primo.
primos = [2,]
print(primos[0])

# só testa números impares
for x in range(3,num2+1,2):
num_divisoes = 0
    # pega o primeiro número e tenta dividi-lo pelos número primos menores que ele.
    for y in primos:
        # Quando o cociente for menor que o divisor para de testar números primos maiores.
        if x//y < y:
            break

        #se der para dividir o número por algum número primo já descoberto então ele não é primo.
        if x % y == 0:
            #marca que ele não é primo.
            num_divisoes = 1
            break

    # se não tiver nenhuma divisão adiciona o número na lista de primos.
    if num_divisoes == 0:
        primos.append(x)
        print(x)
        num_divisoes = 0

print("Existe %i números primos entre 0 e %i"%(len(primos),num2))
fim = time.time()
print("Executado em %.3f segundos"%(fim-inicio))
```

O que fez meu código ficar extremamente rápido foi essa parte:

```
# Quando o cociente for menor que o divisor para de testar números primos maiores.
if x//y < y:
   break
```

Sem esse trecho o número primo 999.983 faria cerca de 78.497 testes para verificar se ele é primo. Como esse código ele faz apenas 169 testes.

Answer (score 0):

Todos os primos até 2.000.000 - leva tempo razoável; para 200.000 é rápido.

```
m = 200000 # para calcular primos até esse número m
# constrói a list comprehension excluindo os divisíveis pelos menores números primos
P = [2] + [3] + [5] + [x for x in range(7,m,2) if x % 3 != 0 and x % 5 != 0]
PL = len(P)
i = 15 # menor composto a excluir tem índice 15: é o 49
while i < PL:
    # Os divisíveis por 2, 3, e 5 já foram excluídos.
    # Começamos a excluir os divíveis de 7, cujo índice na list é 3
    j = 3 # P[3] = 7, menor primo para iniciar teste
    while i < PL and P[j] * P[j] <= P[i]:
    if P[i] % P[j] == 0:
        del P[i]
        PL = len(P)
        i = i - 1
        break
    else:
        j += 1
    i += 1
print(P)
```

Acabei de montar código mais eficiente, que leva 60 segundos:

```
    import time
    inicio = time.time()
    print(inicio)
    m = 2702000
    P = [2] + [3] + [5] + [x for x in range(7,m,2) if x % 3 != 0 and x % 5 != 0]
    PL = len(P)
    C = {P[i] for i in range(15, PL) for j in range(3, int(P[i] ** (1/2))) if P[i] % P[j] == 0}
    P = [P[i] for i in range(PL) if not(P[i] in C)]
    print(P)
    fim = time.time()
    print(fim)
    print("duração: ", fim - inicio)
```

O seguinte código monta a série de primos até 2.000.000 em meio segundo. Para o número sugerido no problema (2.750.159), estoura a memória de meu jupyter. É possível que em outro noteook rode normal:

```
    inicio = time.time()
    print(inicio)
    m = 2000000
    P = [2] + [3] + [5] + [x for x in range(7,m,2) if x % 3 != 0 and x % 5 != 0]
    PL = len(P)
    C = {P[i] * P[j] for i in range(3, int(m ** (1/2))) for j in range(i, int(m ** (1/2)))}
    P = [P[i] for i in range(PL) if not(P[i] in C)]
    print(P)
    fim = time.time()
    print(fim)
    print("duração: ", fim - inicio)
```

Comment: não sei se entndi bm seu algortimo - o tempo é bom, mas não sei por que consome tanta memória. Provavelmente durant a criação do `set` o Python guarda os resultados repetidos temporariamente.
Fiz aqui usando o "crivo de Erastotenes" - em vez de gerar todos os números não primos possíveis e ver quais núemros não estao a lista, começo com uma lista de todos os números  corte os que são múltiplos dos anteriores.

Answer (score -1):

Eu acho que o jeito mais eficiente é, para cada número testar se ele é divisível por algum dos primos menores do que ele.
Exemplo:

```
primos = [2, 3, 5]
...  # Para cada número entre 6 e 200000 define se ele é ou não primo
if num_e_primo:
    primos.append(num)
```

Para 6 basta testar se ele é divisivel por 2, 3, ou 5.
Para 10 teste para 2, 3, 5, e 7
Assim por diante...

Não é necessario testar por todos os numeros, apenas os primos

Exemplo:

Se x for divisivel por 30, ele será divisivel por 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15.

Answer (score -3):

testa esse aqui:

```
"""
Created on Mon Jun 24 14:55:40 2019

@author: Tiago C. Coura
"""

def primeirosprimos(x):


    seq=[2,3,5]
    a=0
    controler=0
    while True:

        a+=1

        if a%2==0:
            r1=3*a+5
        else:
            r1=3*a+4
        if r1%5==0:
            pass
        else:
            z= len(seq)/2
            for loop in seq[0:z]:
                if r1%loop==0 :
                   controler+=1
                   break
            if controler > 0:
                controler=0
                pass
            else:
                seq.append(r1)

        if len(seq)>x-1:
            break

    return seq
```