# Python números primos | while

Tags: python

Tenho o seguinte problema:

Escreva a função maior_primo que recebe um número inteiro maior ou igual a 2 como parâmetro e devolve o maior número primo menor ou igual ao número passado à função

**Note que**

maior_primo(100) deve devolver 97

maior_primo(7) deve devolver 7

**Dica**: escreva uma função éPrimo(k) e faça um laço percorrendo os números até o número dado checando se o número é primo ou não; se for, guarde numa variável. Ao fim do laço, o valor armazenado na variável é o maior primo encontrado.

Minha solução seria:

```
def éPrimo (k):
    div = 2
    while k % div != 0 and div <= k:   
        div = div + 1
        if k % div == 0:
            k = k - 1
        else:
            print (k)
```

Eu estou muitíssimo convencido de que estou certo, ainda estou em um nível muito iniciante e se alguém puder me dar uma luz encima desses parâmetros básicos seria de grande ajuda.

Comment: Cade a função `maior_primo`? O problema até então me parece nela. Se bem que não entendi o enunciado da pergunta por falta de virgulas e pontuação, tem muito texto misturado, tá dificil de ter certeza do que você fez ou escreveu.

Comment: Sim, Realmente LINQ. Parece ser o mesmo curso. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Relacionada: [Como gerar 200.000 primos o mais rápido possível em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/231555/5878)

Answer (score 2):

```
def ehPrimo(x):
    if x >= 2:
        for y in range( 2, x ):
            if not ( x % y ):
                return False
    else:
        return False

    return True

num = int(input("Entre com um numero: "))

for n in range( num, 0, -1 ):
    if ehPrimo(n) :
        print n
        break
```