# Algoritmo para determinar os números primos entre 2 e N. O que está errado?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input("Digite N: "))

lista =[]
divisores =[]
for i in range(2, n+1): 

   for j in range(1,n+1):

       if i>=j:
           if i%j ==0:
               divisores.append(j)
               print("divisores",divisores)
               if len(divisores) ==2:

                   lista.append(i)
                   divisores =[]

print("primos",lista)
```

No algoritmo acima, com N=4, por exemplo, a saída é  [2, 3, 4], o que está errado! Não consegui descobrir o erro no programa! Alguma ideia?

Comment: Por quê o `for` em `j` vai de 1 a `n+1` ao invés de `i+1`?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss: Bom, acho que se fosse até i+1, seria mais eficiente, certo? Mas de qualquer forma, não acho q este seja o erro!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro está na posição em que verificou a quantidade de divisores. Ao fazer a verificação dentro do próprio laço de repetição do `j`, irá ser considerado como primo qualquer número que tenha, pelo menos, dois divisores. Por exemplo, imagine que esteja sendo verificado se o número `i = 6` é primo (e que o valor de `j` varie de 1 a `i`, para facilitar); verificar-se-á que 1 é divisor de 6 e, portanto, será inserido em `divisores`; após, verificar-se-á que 2 é divisor de 6 e também será inserido em `divisores`. Neste ponto, o número 6 possui dois divisores e, portanto, satisfaz a condição `len(divisores) == 2`, considerando, assim, como um número primo. O mesmo acontece com o número 4 do seu exemplo.

Para corrigir, você precisará verificar a quantidade de divisores somente depois de encontrá-los todos, fazendo a verificação fora do laço de repetição:

```
n = int(input("Digite N: "))

lista =[]
divisores =[]
for i in range(2, n+1): 
    for j in range(1, i+1):
        if i >= j:
            if i % j == 0:
                divisores.append(j)
                print("divisores",divisores)
    if len(divisores) == 2:
        lista.append(i)
    divisores = []

print("primos",lista)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/NaiveDeliciousBudgetrange)</sup>

Perceba que, também, reiniciei a lista de divisores fora da condição, para que, independente se o valor for ou não primo, o objeto seja reiniciado antes da próxima iteração do laço.

**Leitura adicional**

- [Como gerar 200.000 primos o mais rápido possível em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231555/como-gerar-200-000-primos-o-mais-r%c3%a1pido-poss%c3%advel-em-python?rq=1)

Uma outra forma de resolver seria criar a função para verificar se um determinado número é primo e utilizá-la em conjunto com uma *list comprehension*:

```
def is_prime(n):
    divisores = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            divisores += 1
    return divisores == 2

N = int(input("Digite N: "))

print([n for n in range(1, N+1) if is_prime(n)])
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/RoyalNavajowhiteActivecell)</sup>

E, utilizando a solução baseada no Crivo de Eratóstenes supracitada, que provavelmente seria a melhor solução das citadas, teríamos:

```
def sieve_of_eratosthene(N):
    A = [True] * (N+1)
    A[0] = A[1] = False
    for value, prime in enumerate(A):
        if prime:
            yield value
            for i in range(value**2, N+1, value):
                A[i] = False

N = int(input("Digite N: "))

print([n for n in sieve_of_eratosthene(N)])
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/FractalFriendlySign)</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigado! Eu tenho muito a aprender!

Answer (score 0):

Para você ter êxito nesta questão você precisa implementar um algoritmo contendo duas `funções`.

1. Uma função para verificar se um `dado número` é primo;
2. Outra função para exibir os números que forem `primos`.

para resolver este problema você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
def exibiprimos():
    """
    Esta função exibi todos os números primos encontrados.
    :return: número primo.
    """
    li = 2
    ls = int(input('Digite o limite superior: '))

    while li <= ls:
        if primo(li) == True:
            print(f'\033[32m{li}', end='')
            print(',' if li < (ls - 1) else '.', end=' ')
        li += 1


def primo(n):
    """
    Esta função verifica se um dado número é ou não primo.
    :param n: número a ser verificado.
    :return: valor booleano.
    """
    i = 1
    cont = 0
    while i <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            cont += 1
        i += 1
    if cont > 2:
        return False
    else:
        return True


exibiprimos()
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/bxqzidct-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Observe que este algoritmo encontrará `todos` os `números primos` que, porventura estiverem entre `2` e `N`.