# Como calcular números perfeitos de forma rápida?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

Estou tentando realizar um exercício para mostrar os números perfeitos presentes dentro de um determinado range, porém eu só consigo realizar tal feito até o quarto número perfeito. Se eu aumentar o range, ele acaba demorando muito tempo e não responde:

```
def perfeito(n_max):
    lista = []
    for n in range(1, n_max + 1):
        soma = 0
        for div in range(1, n):
            if n % div == 0:
                soma += div
        if n == soma:
            lista.append(n)
    return lista
```

Aqui definimos o `range`, neste caso 500, e ele retornará os 3 primeiros:

```
print(perfeito(500))
```

Conjunto números perfeitos: {6, 28, 496, 8128, 33550336, 8589869056, …}

Após o 4º número. não consigo mais exibir. Alguma dica de otimização para meu código?

Answer (score 8):

Existe uma relação direta entre os [números perfeitos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_perfeito) e os [números primos de Mersenne](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primo_de_Mersenne). Um número primo de Mersenne nada mais é que um número primo que pode ser escrito na forma M<sub>n</sub> = 2<sup>n</sup> – 1, para dado `n` inteiro, e a relação dele com os números perfeitos é uma potência de 2. Vale ressaltar na resposta que os conceitos aplicados aqui valem para, apenas, números perfeitos pares, porém a solução se mantém válida dado o fato que ainda não é conhecido pela matemática nenhum número perfeito ímpar - no dia que descobrirem eu edito a solução, prometo.

Assim, dado um número primo de Mersenne M<sub>n</sub> = 2<sup>n</sup> – 1, podemos obter o respectivo número perfeito fazendo P<sub>n</sub> = (2<sup>n-1</sup>) (2<sup>n</sup> – 1).

- P<sub>n=1</sub> = (2<sup>1-1</sup>) (2<sup>1</sup> – 1) = 1
- P<sub>n=2</sub> = (2<sup>2-1</sup>) (2<sup>2</sup> – 1) = 6
- P<sub>n=3</sub> = (2<sup>3-1</sup>) (2<sup>3</sup> – 1) = 28
- P<sub>n=4</sub> = (2<sup>4-1</sup>) (2<sup>4</sup> – 1) = 120
- P<sub>n=5</sub> = (2<sup>5-1</sup>) (2<sup>5</sup> – 1) = 496
- ...

Perceba que quando 2<sup>n</sup> – 1 não é primo, nos casos de n=1 e n=4, o resultado não será um número perfeito. Então o primeiro desafio desta abordagem é garantir que tenhamos como 2<sup>n</sup> – 1 um número primo.

E esse desafio é muito fácil resolver. Matematicamente, podemos definir que 2<sup>n</sup> – 1 é um número primo e, pronto, resolvemos o nosso problema. Porém, resolvendo um, aparece outro: mas 2<sup>n</sup> – 1 é um primo de Mersenne?

Para garantir que o número primo P<sub>n</sub> = 2<sup>n</sup> – 1 seja um primo de Mersenne deve existir um valor inteiro `n` que valide a expressão. Ou seja, se existir um valor `n` tal que n = log<sub>2</sub>(P<sub>n</sub>+1) seja inteiro, então P<sub>n</sub> será um primo de Mersenne.

A abordagem consistirá, então, de percorrer a lista de números primos, verificar se é um primo de Mersenne e, quando for, calcular o respectivo número perfeito. Com sorte, nós já sabemos calcular os números primos de uma forma eficiente

- [Como gerar 200.000 primos o mais rápido possível em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/231555/5878)

Então basta percorrer esses valores e verificar quais são primos de Mersenne, calculando o número perfeito:

```
# Percorre a lista de números primos menores que N:
for prime in sieve_of_eratosthene(N):

    # Calcula o valor de n que define o Pn:
    n = math.log2(prime+1)

    # Verifica se n é inteiro, sendo um primo de Mersenne:
    is_mersenne = n.is_integer()

    # Se for um primo de Mersenne, calcula o número perfeito:
    if is_mersenne:
        print(2**(n-1) * prime)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/GlumStunningRouter) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/gY8vcH) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/acwoss/11a23bd1336f643d5abc0210170a00fd)</sup>

Assim, testando aqui, ele levou cerca de 34 segundos para calcular até o número perfeito 137438691328. Acima disso comecei a ter problemas com memória, que buscarei resolver em breve.

**Referências adicionais**

Dois vídeos que recomendo assistir sobre o assunto são:

- [Perfect Numbers and Mersenne Primes - Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0xKHwQH-4I)
- [Perfect Number Proof - Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8n15q1v4Xo)

---

Buscando otimizar o código, consegui fazer sem utilizar o Sieve. Basicamente o que o código faz é definir um gerador que retorna todos os números primos de Mersenne verificando se o número é primo e utilizando o [teste de primalidade de Lucas-Lehmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test).

```
def is_prime(number):
    # Condição para number=2 ignorada propositalmente, visto que a menor entrada será 3
    i = 3
    while i**2 <= number:
        if number % i == 0:
            return False
        i += 2
    return True

def lucas_lehmer(p):
    s = 4
    M = 2**p - 1

    for _ in range(p - 2):
        s = ((s * s) - 2) % M
    return s == 0

def mersenne_primes():
    p = 3
    while True:
        if is_prime(p) and lucas_lehmer(p):
            yield (p, 2**p - 1)
        p += 2
```

Para utilizá-lo, por exemplo, buscando os 10 primeiros números perfeitos, basta fazer:

```
numbers = mersenne_primes()

for _ in range(10):
    p, mersenne = next(numbers)
    perfect = 2**(p-1) * mersenne
    print(perfect)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/QuickDarkbluePublishers) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/EFaHZK) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/acwoss/bbd8738b37c23918ee66e3b0c365eb55)</sup>

Alguns resultados que obtive:

- Para os [10 primeiros](https://ideone.com/EFaHZK) números perfeitos: 0.0003993511199951172s
- Para os [15 primeiros](https://ideone.com/TZotiC) números perfeitos: 1.9178969860076904s
- Para os [16 primeiros](https://repl.it/@acwoss/BusyUnhappyDatabase) números perfeitos: 6.957615613937378s
- Para os [17 primeiros](https://repl.it/@acwoss/LightyellowLovableDeclarations) números perfeitos: 28.416791677474976s
- Para os [18 primeiros](https://repl.it/@acwoss/SpecializedFrillyProblems) números perfeitos: 78.89492082595825s
- Para os [19 primeiros](https://repl.it/@acwoss/TightApprehensiveInterface) números perfeitos: 93.7487268447876s

Para 20 eu fiquei com preguiça de esperar.

Comment: "*Euclides demonstrou que o número 2**(p-1)*(2**p-1) é um número perfeito par se p for um número primo*" - Isso é um "*se*", ou é um "*se, e somente se*"?

Comment: @VictorStafusa bom ponto - e com isso percebi que faltaram as referências ali

Comment: E para o caso de números perfeitos ímpares? Ninguém nunca conseguiu descobrir um, mas também ninguém nunca conseguiu provar que não existem. Esse teorema de Euclides serve para os números perfeitos pares apenas.

Comment: Basta inserir o laço for abaixo do : yield perfect_number e pedir para ir printando?

Comment: Só para lembrar, não basta, ser número primo para gerar números perfeitos, tem que ser os Primos Mersenne --> https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primo_de_Mersenne

Comment: @weltonvaz sim, isso está comentado bem no início da resposta, na nota.

Comment: @anderson-carlos-woss Só foi citado a fórmula, NÃO o tipo de Números Primos! Por senão pode pensar que qualquer número primo geraria número perfeito!

Comment: @weltonvaz resposta reformulada, veja se ficou mais claro assim :D

Comment: @anderson-carlos-woss valeu cara, ficou muito, muito melhor. Desculpe se fui inconveniente, mas sou obstinado(ou melhor louco mesmo) para achar um fórmula, para Números Primos de Mersenne. Que podesse ser resolver em tempo polinomial por uma Máquina de Turing não determinística!

Comment: @weltonvaz inconveniente nenhum, qualquer coisa que seja para colaborar com a qualidade sempre é bem-vinda. Se quiser, temos o [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) para conversas mais diretas.

Comment: "*ainda não é conhecido pela matemática nenhum número perfeito ímpar - no dia que descobrirem eu edito a solução, prometo*" - Você acha que isso é antes ou depois de resolverem o problema P=NP? Será que até semana que vem já acham algum número perfeito ímpar?

Comment: Acredito que quando Vc falou isso, fez como brincadeira. Mas como a matemática é sempre surpreendente, olha esse materia que acabei de ler:  
Matemático afirma que resolveu problema de 160 anos que vale US$ 1 milhão - Revista -Galileu - A teoria afirma que a distribuição de números primos não é aleatória (como é classificada), mas pode seguir um padrão descrito por uma equação. https://revistagalileu.globo.com/Ciencia/noticia/2018/09/matematico-afirma-que-resolveu-problema-de-160-anos-que-vale-us-1-milhao.htm

Comment: https://revistagalileu.globo.com/Ciencia/noticia/2018/09/matematico-afirma-que-resolveu-problema-de-160-anos-que-vale-us-1-milhao.html

Answer (score 7):

O seu programa apenas está levando um tempo muuuuuuito longo para calcular.

Observe que você tem um `for` dentro do outro. O laço de fora vai rodar mais de 33 milhões de vezes para achar o 5º número. O laço de dentro vai percorrer em cada iteração o mesmo valor do número do laço externo menos 1.

Se o laço externo roda `n_max` vezes, isso significa que o laço de dentro vai acabar executando um número de vezes igual `n_max * (n_max - 1)`. Se `n_max` for 33550336, então o laço interno vai ter que rodar 1.125.625.012.162.560 de vezes até que o quinto número seja encontrado. Para chegar a esse número de mais de um quadrilhão de iterações, é possível que o programa leve alguns dias.

Já para encontrar o 8589869056, ele provavelmente levaria anos.

É possível fazer algumas simplificações:

- Cortar o laço interno quando `soma` ultrapassar `n`.
- Quando você encontra que `n % div == 0`, você encontra dois divisores, e não apenas um. Um deles é `div` e o outro é `n / div`. Com isso, você consegue diminuir o limite superior da iteração e só precisa ir até a raiz quadrada de `n`.
- Já fazer `soma` começar com 1 e começar a testar a partir do 2. Pode parecer bobo, mas sem isso as duas otimizações anteriores não funciona porque ao achar o 1, ele também acharia o `n` e cortaria o laço imediatamente.

Com isso, é possível otimizar o laço interno mais ou menos assim:

```
soma = 1
for div in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))):
    if n % div == 0:
        soma += div
        div2 = int(n / div)
        if (div != div2):
            soma += div2
        if soma > n:
            break
```

Você também pode acrescentar um parâmetro `n_min` e ao invés de percorrer de 1 até `n_max`, percorrer de `n_min` até `n_max`. Com essas mudanças, ao pesquisar os números perfeitos no intervalo 33550337 e 33550338, ele acha o 33550336 num piscar de olhos.

O código completo fica assim:

```
import math

def perfeito(n_min, n_max):
    lista = []
    for n in range(n_min, n_max + 1):
        soma = 1
        for div in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))):
            if n % div == 0:
                soma += div
                div2 = int(n / div)
                if (div != div2):
                    soma += div2
                if soma > n:
                    break
        if n == soma:
            lista.append(n)
    return lista

print(perfeito(33550335, 33550337))
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/Mk9MuG)

Tentei usando `print(perfeito(2, 33550337))`. Os números 6, 28, 496 e 8128 surgiram em milisegundos (coloquei um `print` antes do `append` para ver isso). No entanto, ainda demora várias horas para o 33550336 aparecer.

Answer (score 4):

Somando às resposta já publicadas, um ponto a ser notado é que todo o número perfeito é um [número hexagonal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_hexagonal). Então, ao invés de testar um por um dos números, você pode percorrer apenas os números hexagonais. Ex:

```
def gen_hexagonal():
    n = 1
    while True:
        yield (2 * n * (2 * n - 1)) // 2
        n += 1

for i, num in gen_hexagonal():
    print(num)

# 1, 6, 15, 28, 45, 66, 91, 120, 153, 190, 231, 276, 325, 378, 435, ...
```

[Exemplo funcionando](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/WryUnsungApplet)