# Tempo de execução excedido em c

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um programa que some a quantidade de números primos de 1 até 2000.000. Ao tentar compilar, ele retorna que houve tempo de execução excedido.
Gostaria de saber maneiras de otimizar o tempo do meu programa.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
      long long int i = 0, j = 0, count = 0, soma = 0;

      for (j = 1; j <= 2000000; j++, count = 0)
      {

        for (i = 1; i <= 2000000; i++)
        {
          if (j % i == 0)
          {
            count++;
          }
        }

        if (count == 2)
        {
          soma += + j;
        }

      }
      printf("%lld\n", soma);

return 0;
    }
```

Comment: O que você está a procura é isto [Como gerar 200.000 primos o mais rápido possível em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231555/como-gerar-200-000-primos-o-mais-r%C3%A1pido-poss%C3%ADvel-em-python) que utiliza o *Crivo de Eratóstenes* que é o pormenor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua verificação da primalidade do número está bastante ineficiente. Na verdade não verifica se o número é primo.

Você pode otimizar a verificação eliminando uma boa parte dos cálculos usando:

```
bool ehprimo(int n) {
    int i;
    if (n == 2)
        return true;
    else
        if ((n < 2) || (n % 2 == 0))
            return false;
        else {
            i = 3;
            while ((i <= sqrt(n)) && (n%i != 0))
                i += 2;
            return (i>sqrt(n));
        }
}
```

As considerações são:

- -1, 0 e 1 não são primos por definição;
- o único par primo é o 2, qualquer múltiplo de 2 é divisível por 2;
- você só precisa verificar se os ímpares não tem nenhum divisor entre
  3 e raiz quadrada(n).

Creio que você se expressou mal ao dizer "some a quantidade de números primos", me parece que você quer apenas calcular a quantidade e não vai somar tal quantidade a nada. Ou, talvez, você queira dizer a soma dos primos no intervalo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a fórmula da soma dos termos de uma P.A. para calcular.

```
Sn = ((a1+an)*n)/2. No caso Sn = ((1+2000000)*2000000)/2)
```

Comment: Fiquei um pouco confuso sobre como usar isso no código, poderia me explicar melhor?

Comment: Note que a sequência de números primos não forma uma Progressão Aritmética.