# Formatar saída em arquivo txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
def verificaPrimo(num):
    if int(num) < 2:
        return False
    else:
        for n in range(2, int(num)):
            if int(num) % int(n) == 0:
                return False
        return True


def obtemNumeros(nomeArquivo):
    arquivo = open(nomeArquivo, "r")
    linha = arquivo.readline()
    numeros  = linha.split()
    for line in arquivo:
        numeros += line.split()
    arquivo.close()
    return numeros


arq = open("resultPrimos.txt", "w")
nomeArquivo = "numeros.txt"
numeros = obtemNumeros(nomeArquivo)
for numero in numeros:
    verificaPrimo(numero)
    if verificaPrimo(numero) == True:
        arq.write(numero)
        arq.write("\n")
arq.close()
```

As verificações está OK, gerar o arquivo de saída está OK também, escrever os números primos nesse arquivo está OK também.

O meu problema é o seguinte:

No meu arquivo de entrada, que é o arquivo numeros.txt, o conteúdo dele é:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
50 -13 13 11
1
2
3
```

A saída que obtenho no arquivo resultPrimos.txt é:

```
2
3
5
7
13
11
2
3
```

Preciso que a saída seja da seguinte forma:

```
2 3 5 7
13 11

2
3
```

Poderiam me ajudar?

OBS: sim, na linha onde não houver números primos, deve printar uma linha em branco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Santana, como você quer manter os dados nas respectivas linhas, pensei que usar uma lista de vetores seria uma alternativa:

```
def verificaPrimo(num):
  if int(num) < 2:
    return False
  else:
    for n in range(2, int(num)):
      if int(num) % int(n) == 0:
        return False
    return True


def obtemNumeros(nomeArquivo):
  arquivo = open(nomeArquivo, "r")
  numeros = []
  for line in arquivo:
    numeros.append(line.replace("\n", "").split(" "))
  arquivo.close()
  return numeros


arq = open("resultPrimos.txt", "w")
nomeArquivo = "numeros.txt"
numeros = obtemNumeros(nomeArquivo)
for linha in numeros:
  primos = ""
  for numero in linha:
    if verificaPrimo(numero):
      primos += numero + " "

  arq.write(primos + "\n")
arq.close()
```

Dessa forma, cada posição da lista, é uma linha que contém os números que serão avaliados e escritos, conforme condição, assim sempre uma linha será escrita no arquivo, mesmo que em branco.

Porém com isso, tive de criar dois loops, um para a lista e um para o seu conteúdo.

Answer (score 3):

Podes escrever exatamente na mesma linha onde encontraste esses primos.

Sugerindo outra forma de fazer mas obtendo o resultado esperado:

```
def verificaPrimo(num): 
    return all(num%i!=0 for i in range(2,num)) and num > 1 # se o modulo de todos os num ate este for diferente de 0 e maior que 1

def obtemNumeros(nomeArquivo):
    with open(nomeArquivo, "r") as f:
      for l in f:
        yield l.split()

nomeArquivo = "numeros.txt"
txt_write = ''
for nums in obtemNumeros(nomeArquivo):
    txt_write += '{}\n'.format(' '.join([i for i in nums if verificaPrimo(int(i))])) # filtrar os primos e contruir o texto desta linha 
print(txt_write.strip(), file=open("resultPrimos.txt", 'w')) # escrever no ficheiro e remover ultima quebra de linha com o strip()
```

Output:

```
2 3 5 7
13 11

2
3
```

Com esta abordagem estamos a construir o texto a escrever no `resultPrimos.txt` ao mesmo tempo que vamos percorrendo o arquivo que estamos a ler (`numeros.txt`).

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/BrokenGrotesqueTrapezoid)

Não para este específico problema, mas recomendo veres esta publicação: [Como gerar 200.000 primos o mais rápido possível em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231555/como-gerar-200-000-primos-o-mais-r%C3%A1pido-poss%C3%ADvel-em-python/231668)