# Corrigir loop infinito

Tags: python

Olá,

Fiz um código para uma função que dá loop infinito sempre que a chamo mas não consigo entender o motivo.
Segue o código:

```
def geraprimos(qtd, inicio, fim):
    lista = []
    while len(lista) < qtd:
        numero = random.randint(inicio, fim)
        metade = numero//2       
        for i in range(2, metade):
            if numero%i == 0:
                next
            elif i == metade:
                lista.append(numero)
    return lista
```

Comment: Deveria ser range `range(2, metade + 1)`, pois a função `range` não inclui o delimitador final no iterador, de forma que se você utilizar `range(2, metade)`, `i` nunca será igual a `metade`.

Comment: Gerar uma lista de números primos sorteando-os aleatoriamente não é uma boa ideia. Recomendo ler sobre algoritmos mais otimizados para isso, como o [Crivo de Eratóstenes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/231668/5878).

Answer (score 0):

Sua função está no loop infinito pq não há alteração na sua condição do Loop, assim fica sempre a mesma coisa.

No caso o erro está no `range` do seu `for`. A função `range` pega o intervalo de números contando com o primeiro número. Exemplo:

- `for x in range(3)` = `for x in range (0,3)` -> x = [0,1,2] (resultado)

No seu caso (`for i in range(2, metade):`) o `i` vai ser `2 <= x < metade`, assim nunca vai ser igual a variável `metade` e nunca vai entrar na condição `elif i == metade:` que também não vai adicionar na lista (`lista.append(numero)`) que não vai alterar a condição de parada do seu `while` (`while len(lista) < qtd`), porque sua lista vai estar sempre vazia..

Para concertar isso eh bem simples, pode ser na condição do `for` ou do `elif`:

> Método 01: soma `+1` no `fr`

```
def geraprimos(qtd, inicio, fim):
    lista = []
    while len(lista) < qtd:
        numero = random.randint(inicio, fim)
        metade = numero//2       
        for i in range(2, metade + 1):          # Alteração
            if numero%i == 0:
                next
            elif i == metade:
                lista.append(numero)
    return lista
```

> Método 02: soma `+1` no `elif`

```
def geraprimos(qtd, inicio, fim):
    lista = []
    while len(lista) < qtd:
        numero = random.randint(inicio, fim)
        metade = numero//2       
        for i in range(2, metade):
            if numero%i == 0:
                next
            elif i == metade +1:                # Alteração
                lista.append(numero)
    return lista
```

Comment: Atente-se também ao `next` utilizado neste código...

Comment: Sim, eh vdd. Eu esqueci de colocar isso pq quando testei tirei isso pq eh uma condição desnecessaria