# Gerar uma lista de números primos até 1000. Esses números deverão formar uma lista, LPrimos. depois verificar em LPrimos se ele é primo ou não

Tags: python, python-3.x

Criei um algoritmo que imprima a lista, porém estou tendo dificuldades em fazer a repetição que faça a busca na lista, estou usando o if X in Lista, porém não estou conseguindo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

A repetição seria de S/N, S para continuar e N para parar

```
def primo(m):
    i = 1
    cont = 0
    while i <= m:
        if m % i == 0:
            cont += 1
        i += 1
    if cont > 2:
        return False
    else:
        return True

num = 1000

li = 2
LPrimos = []
while li <= num:
    if primo(li):
        LPrimos.append(li)
    li += 1

print(LPrimos)

num = int(input('digite o número, digite "0" para parar o programa'))

while num != 0:
    if num in LPrimos:
        print('É primo')
    else:
        print('Não é primo')
```

Comment: Entendi, mas devo depois, criar um input, por exemplo 875 e fazer com que o algoritmo procure nessa lista de números primos se o número 875 está dentro dela. E se estiver, imprimir que é primo, se não, imprimir que não é.

Comment: `if X in Lista` deveria funcionar, considerando que "Lista" na verdade seja "LPrimos". Se não está funcionando, por favor, atualize a pergunta com esse trecho de código também.

Comment: Aliás, o que seria esse `for` com a variável `mult`? Ele não tem objetivo algum no seu código. Esqueceu de excluí-lo?

Comment: Sim, eu atualizei a pergunta, quando eu dou um run, e testo, mesmo colocando um número que se encontra dentro da lista, ele marca como se não fosse primo. E como eu poderia também fazer uma repetição para s/n?

Comment: Então, o retorno da função `input` é sempre uma string. Se você digitar 37, `num` será `"37"`. Como sua lista é composta de inteiros e você está pesquisando por uma string nunca encontrará mesmo. Converta `num` para inteiro antes de fazer a busca.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado.

Comment: Eu coloquei para parar quando for 0, mas o programa gera um loop e não para, fica printando a resposta infinitamente, qual o motivo disso?

Comment: Você faz a leitura uma única vez **fora** do loop.

Answer (score 2):

Para gerar a lista com todos os primos até determinado número, dá para usar algoritmos melhores, como o Crivo de Eratóstenes (tem inclusive uma implementação completa [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/231668/112052) - mas como *parece* ser um exercício, talvez você não possa usá-lo). Mas apenas para dar uma outra alternativa melhor que o seu código, basta considerar que:

- Com exceção do 2, todos os outros números pares não são primos. Ou seja, a partir do 3, eu só preciso testar os números ímpares.
- Eu não preciso testar se o número é divisível por números pares (pois neste caso ele seria divisível por 2, e portanto, par, e portanto, não seria primo). Na verdade, eu só preciso testar se é divisível por algum número primo. Qualquer outro teste é redundante.

E como você já está construindo uma lista com todos os números primos, basta usá-la na própria verificação:

```
# adicionar n na lista de primos, caso seja
def adiciona_se_primo(n, primos):
    limite = n // 2
    # verifica se n é divisível por algum dos números primos já encontrados
    for p in primos:
        # se já passou da metade de n, não terá mais nenhum divisor e posso parar o for
        if p > limite:
            break # sai do loop, já sei que é primo
        if n % p == 0:
            return # retorna (não é primo)
    primos.append(n)

LPrimos = [2] # já posso começar com o 2 (o único número par que é primo)

# constrói a lista com todos os primos até 1000
for n in range(3, 1000, 2): # range de 2 em 2 para só pegar os ímpares
    adiciona_se_primo(n, LPrimos)
```

Primeiro eu inicio a lista de primos com o 2. Depois eu faço um *loop* com os números ímpares até 1000 (começando do 3), e vou adicionando os primos encontrados em `LPrimos`. O interessante é que eu uso a própria lista de primos para verificar se `n` é primo, e atualizo esta lista caso seja.

Veja que na função `adiciona_se_primo` eu só verifico se `n` é divisível por algum número primo, pois não preciso testar se ele é divisível por todos os números, é redundante. E também não preciso ir até o fim, se já passei da metade de `n`, dali em diante não terá nenhum divisor de `n` e portanto eu já sei que ele é primo e posso interromper o *loop*.

Ao final, teremos a lista com todos os primos menores que 1000.

---

Agora a segunda parte. Veja o seu *loop*:

```
num = int(input('digite o número, digite "0" para parar o programa'))

while num != 0:
    if num in LPrimos:
        print('É primo')
    else:
        print('Não é primo')
```

Enquanto `num` for diferente de zero, o `while` continua rodando. Mas dentro do *loop* você nunca muda o valor de `num`. Ou seja, se ele não for zero, ele entra no `while` e não sai nunca mais. Provavelmente o que você quer é algo assim:

```
# agora que já tenho a lista de números primos, basta fazer o *loop*
while True:
    num = int(input('digite o número, digite "0" para parar o programa'))
    if num == 0:
        break
    if num in LPrimos:
        print(f'{num} é primo')
    else:
        print(f'{num} não é primo')
```

Ou seja, faço a leitura do valor **dentro** do `while`, e se ele for zero, eu uso `break` para sair do *loop*.

[Tem gente que "não gosta" de `break`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131093/112052) e prefere fazer algo assim:

```
num = 1
while num != 0:
    num = int(input('digite o número, digite "0" para parar o programa'))
    if num != 0:
        if num in LPrimos:
            print(f'{num} é primo')
        else:
            print(f'{num} não é primo')
```

Mas eu acho pior. Primeiro porque tem que inicializar a variável com algum valor artificial só para entrar no *loop*, e depois tem que colocar um `if` a mais para não considerar o zero (senão ele ia imprimir que zero não é primo, mas entendo que o zero só serve para encerrar e portanto não deveria ser testado).

Answer (score 0):

Entendendo "Gerar uma lista de números primos até 1000" como uma lista com todos os números primos menores que 1.000, tente:

```
def ehprimo(num,primos):
    for divi in primos:
        if num%divi == 0:
            return False
    return True

num,cont,primos = 2,1,[]
while num <= 1000:
    if ehprimo(num,primos) == True:
        cont += 1
        print(num)
        primos.append(num)
    num += 1
print(primos)
```